# How to add new grid into grid in code with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid

How can I add dynamically a grid into another grid? I can't do this:

```
myGrid.Children.Add(dg);
```

Because I don't have the instance of this grid - I'm using MVVM.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, since you mention MVVM, that you want to accomplish this from your View Model?

In that case my suggestion is to send a message from the View Model to the View. 
In the View you add a subscription to this message and add the Grid from there.

You could do it something like this, in its most simple form. This would be using the excellent [MVVM Light framework](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/):

`ViewModel.cs:`

```
private void CreateGrid()
{
  Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("CreateGrid"));
}
```

`View.xaml.cs:`

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, nm =>
{
  if (nm.Notification != "CreateGrid") return;
  // Create grid here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're dynamically adding controls at runtime, the short answer is that you probably aren't going to be successful doing that via MVVM.  Dropping that into the codebehind may be your best bet-- without knowing what kind of app you're building, it is hard to pass judgement and demand loudly that you MUST use MVVM.

That being said, I rarely find myself in a situation with WPF where I have to do dynamic control manipulation like that.  Instead, I wind up using different WPF constructs (ListBox, ContentControl, ItemsControl, etc.), along with things like ItemTemplates to get what I want.

Again, without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, it's difficult to give any kind of prescriptive guidance.

Comment: Writing code-behind doesn't mean it's not possible to use MVVM. As long as the code-behind is related to the view only (and creating controls at runtime is purely related to the view) then IMO it's totally fine with the pattern.

Comment: @ken2k I agree.  The original post was asking how to accomplish that from an MVVM perspective, which is why I answered the way I did. I don't think the use of codebehind obviates the implementation of an MVVM approach elsewhere in the application.